# Does having a keyword in the domain repeated again in the path of the URL hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, url, keywords

Which of the following URL structures would be best for a non-ecommerce site:

`fishingbob.com/fishing-lure-companies`

or

`fishingbob.com/lure-companies`

Would repeating the keyword in the first URL be considered keyword stuffing since I have an important keyword already in my domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does having a keyword in the domain repeated again in the path of the URL hurt SEO?

No.

> Which of the following URL structures would be best...

Best for SEO - either. Best for users - probably the shorter one. "fishing-lure-companies" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to me? URLs that are better for "users" indirectly benefit SEO.

> Would repeating the keyword in the first URL be considered keyword stuffing

No.

Bear in mind that "keywords" in the URL carry very little weight in terms of direct SEO (a factor that, by itself, would directly affect ranking). On page *content* is the key here.

URLs are primarily for *users* and can help click through rates. Search engines don't care so much. `/?id=123` or `/fishing-lure-companies` - it's really the *content* that the search engines care about.